# VBA Storing multiple columns in array during a loop then return value

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a macro that applies a user defined function (R.ajseasonX13 in the code) to multiple columns in worksheet "NSA", and then returns the values in the worksheet "SA".

The issue is that my code applies the function to the columns only one at a time. This turns out to be very slow, once that VBA keeps going back and forth from the tabs "NSA" to "SA".

I know how to create a range with all of the columns that need to modified with the function "R.ajseasonX13". My doubt is: how to apply the function to which one of the columns, store all of the columns in a matrix as the code runs and then return only this final matrix with the adjusted values?

I have tried to create an Array, but I am stuck on how to identify the first row with numeric data and how to add the new columns to it as the For loop goes.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Dessaz()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

Dim wsNSA As Worksheet
Set wsNSA = wb1.Worksheets("NSA")

Dim wsSA As Worksheet
Set wsSA = wb1.Worksheets("SA")

Dim col As Range
Dim nsaArray As Variant

'Finds the row of the first cell with numeric data in column A (where dates are stored)
wsNSA.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1048576, 1)).NumberFormat = "General"
datas_col = wsNSA.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10000, 1))
data1_linha = Application.Match(True, Application.Index(Application.IsNumber(datas_col), 0), 0)
wsNSA.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1048576, 1)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

'Determinates one of the parameters of the user defined function "R.ajseasonX13" used ahead
inicio = wsNSA.Cells(data1_linha, 1).Value
inicio = Year(inicio) & "-" & Month(inicio) & "-" & "01"

'LR is the last column with data and LC is the last column with data
LR = wsNSA.Cells(data1_linha, 1).End(xlDown).Row
LC = wsNSA.Cells(LR, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

'States another one of the parameters of the user defined function
p = 12

nsaArray = wsNSA.Range(wsNSA.Cells(1, 2), wsNSA.Cells(LR, LC))
For Each col In wsNSA.Range(wsNSA.Cells(1, 2), wsNSA.Cells(LR, LC))
  wsNSA.Activate
  nsa = wsNSA.Range(wsNSA.Cells(1, col.Column), wsNSA.Cells(LR, col.Column))

'Finds the first row with numeric data in each column of the data series
  num_linha = Application.Match(True, Application.Index(Application.IsNumber(nsa), 0), 0)
  nsaArray = wsNSA.Range(wsNSA.Cells(num_linha, col.Column), wsNSA.Cells(LR, col.Column))

'Applies the user defined function to the "nsa" columns and returns their value (but only one at a time, which is
'not as fast as possivle in VBA
'wsSA.Activate
  sa = Application.Run("R.ajseasonX13", nsa, inicio, p)
  wsSA.Range(wsSA.Cells(num_linha, col.Column), wsSA.Cells(LR, col.Column)) = sa
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Would you please post the function to be applied…