# VBA adding columns to array as loop occurs

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

My macro needs to perform a seasonal adjustment with the "R.ajseasonX13" function (which was made with the BERT toolkit that allows users to create Execl functions from R, but this is not essential to the answer, just so you know what I am trying to accomplish).

I want the function to be applied to a certain range. As to grant VBA more speed running the code, I intend to transform the range in an array (the "nsaArray" in the code), apply the "R.ajseasonx13" function (which is a CSE formula) to each column of the array and put all of these transformed columns (they are generated by the variable "sa" each time the loop is performed) together in a new array, thus creating a "temporary matrix" holding my adjusted values. Having this matrix, I want to simply print its values in another worksheet.

I can define the array, loop through it and apply the function just fine, but when it comes to mounting a new matrix with the desired values, I fail, because the worksheet range results in blank cells.

How can I assign all of the values from the "sa" variable (which is a vector for each column in the array) in a new array after each loop runs?

Here is my code:

```
Sub Dessaz()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

Dim wsNSA As Worksheet
Set wsNSA = wb1.Worksheets("NSA")

Dim wsSA As Worksheet
Set wsSA = wb1.Worksheets("SA")

Dim col As Range

Dim nsaArray() As Variant

'Finds the row of the first cell with numeric data in column A (where dates are stored)
wsNSA.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1048576, 1)).NumberFormat = "General"
datas_col = wsNSA.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10000, 1))
data1_linha = Application.Match(True, Application.Index(Application.IsNumber(datas_col), 0), 0)
wsNSA.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1048576, 1)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

'Determinates one of the parameters of the user defined function "R.ajseasonX13" used ahead
inicio = wsNSA.Cells(data1_linha, 1).Value
inicio = Year(inicio) & "-" & Month(inicio) & "-" & "01"

'LR is the last column with data and LC is the last column with data
LR = wsNSA.Cells(data1_linha, 1).End(xlDown).Row
LC = wsNSA.Cells(LR, 1).End(xlToRight).Column


'States another one of the parameters of the user defined function

    p = 12


'Working with arrays instead of ranges in VBA
'ReDim nsaArray(1 To LR - 1 - num_linha, 1 To LC - 1)
nsaArray = wsNSA.Range(wsNSA.Cells(1, 2), wsNSA.Cells(LR, LC)).Value
    MsgBox (LBound(nsaArray, 1))

For i = LBound(nsaArray, 2) To UBound(nsaArray, 2)
    x = Application.Index(nsaArray, 0, i)
    sa = Application.Run("R.ajseasonX13", x, inicio, p)

    For j = LBound(nsaArray, 1) To UBound(nsaArray, 1)
    nsaArray(j, i) = sa

    Next

Next


    wsSA.Range(wsSA.Cells(1, 2), wsSA.Cells(LR, LC)) = nsaArray

End sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `sa` when it is returned from your R function?  Try temporarily changing `sa = Application.Run("R.ajseasonX13", x, inicio, p)` to `sa = i` and see whether you get results written out.

Comment: How is this different than [the question you posted earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227325/vba-storing-multiple-columns-in-array-during-a-loop-then-return-value)?